# Cordova file plugin reader

Tags: file, cordova, plugins, filereader

In my recent project i'm using the cordova file plugin.
I have no trouble adding files to my device root. But when i try to read them it doesn't go trough the `onloadend` function.

Any ideas ??

function readtextfile() {

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("test.txt", { create: true }, function (f) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        alert(e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsText(f);
}, onError);
```

}

Comment: You have to use fullpath + file name

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. The documentation and examples weren't very clear to me. Try `onload` instead of `onloadend`:

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
    alert(e.target.result);
};
```